# Getting error when try to execute source command from Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

- name: Create a virtual folder for Airflow
        shell: python3.6 -m venv {{ directory }}

  ```
  - name: Active virtual Environment
    shell: chdir={{ directory }} && source bin/activate
  ```

### Getting below Error

```
TASK [Active virtual Environment] **************************************************************
fatal: [host2.domain.local]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "&& source bin/activate", "delta": "0:00:00.003346", "end": "2019-01-30 20:56:13.119072", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-01-30 20:56:13.115726", "stderr": "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'\n/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `&& source bin/activate'", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'", "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `&& source bin/activate'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- name: Active virtual Environment
  shell: source bin/activate
  args:
    chdir: {{ directory }}
```

try this